# Помогите с сортировкой объектов внутри массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

у меня есть массив с объектами подскажите как сделать так чтоб у объектов у которых второе значение цифра помешались в верх а которых второй параметр надпись помешались в конец массива заранее спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> подскажите как сделать так чтоб у объектов у которых второе значение цифра помешались в верх а которых второй параметр надпись помешались в конец

Можно так:

```js
var months = [
  ['March', 'Rank not found'],
  ['Jan', '154'],
  ['Feb', '1020'],
  ['Dec', '33'], 
  ['Dec', 'Rank not found'],
  ['Feb', '10420'],
];
months.sort(function(a, b) {
  // Сравнения по строкам
   // return a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);
   return +a[1] &&  +b[1]
     ? Number.parseInt(a[1]) - Number.parseInt(b[1]) 
      : a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);
});


console.log(months);
```

---

Или так если надо сортировать, строки типа цифр.

```js
var months = [
  ['March', 'Rank not found'],
  ['Jan', '154'],
  ['Feb', '1020'],
  ['Dec', '33'], 
  ['Dec', 'Rank not found'],
  ['Feb', '10420'],
];
months.sort(function(a, b) {
  // Сравнения по строкам или по цифрам
   return +a[1] &&  +b[1]
     ? (+a[1]) - (+b[1]) // или так кому как нарвиться
      : a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);
});


console.log(months);
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек)